# Loop create an element with pikaday (dynamic create a calendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create dynamic calendar with pikaday libs and jQuery.

So I try

```
var today = moment();
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
var m = today.add(1, "months");
var field = '<div class="input-field">'+
            '<input type="text" name="date_will'+i+'" id="date_will'+i+'" value="'+m.format('DD/MM/YYYY')+'" required>'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="date_will_h'+i+'" id="date_will_h'+i+'" value>'+
            '</div>';
$('.newform').append(field);

$('#date_will'+i).pikaday({
                onSelect: function() {
                    console.log($('#date_will_h'+i));
                    $('#date_will_h'+i).prop('value', this.getMoment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                }
            });
}
```

It work fine but when I want to use `onSelect` event I can't detect the real selector I try to `console.log($('#date_will_h'+i));` it show the last i `i = 5` to all of my calendar.

How can I get the real selector?

Thanks.

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5ozk0cs/

Now I solved this using `bind` : http://jsfiddle.net/m5ozk0cs/1/

Comment: Many thanks @Arun P Johny.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vq6yLd2c/1/

Comment: Thanks again @ArunPJohny, But your solution make the wrong years. This is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/m5ozk0cs/1/.